# php - compare two strings

Tags: php, string, compare

I have this part of PHP code:

```
<?php
$dns = file_get_contents('./dns.txt');

$dns2 = 'serverquery://name:pass@example.com:10011/?server_port=9987&use_offline_as_virtual=1&no_query_clients=1';

$dns3 = 'serverquery://name:pass@' . $dns . ':10011/?server_port=9987&use_offline_as_virtual=1&no_query_clients=1';

if (strcmp($dns2, $dns3) !== 0) {
    echo '$dns2 is not equal to $dns3';
}

echo '<br><br>DNS<br>';
print $dns;
echo '<br><br>DNS2<br>';
print $dns2;
echo '<br><br>DNS3<br>';
print $dns3;
echo '<br><br><br>';

?>
```

file dns.txt contais only text *example.com* without any space at the begin or at the end

when I run this code, the result is:

```
$dns2 is not equal to $dns3

DNS
﻿example.com

DNS2
serverquery://name:pass@example.com:10011/?server_port=9987&use_offline_as_virtual=1&no_query_clients=1

DNS3
serverquery://name:pass@﻿example.com:10011/?server_port=9987&use_offline_as_virtual=1&no_query_clients=1
```

i'm trying to create serverquery for TeamSpeak 3 server and it only works if I use *$dns2* and I want it to work with *$dns3*

so my question is: why *$dns2* is not equal to *$dns3* ?

can you please help me ?

Comment: Use `var_dump()` to verify the contents of the file and see whether it really contains what you think it does

Comment: you are right... but why they are not the same? 
DNS:(length=14) DNS2:(length=103) DNS3:(length=106)

Comment: Also look at the actual output and you will have your answer.

Comment: im trying but i cant see any diference :/ **string 'serverquery://name:pass@example.com:10011/?server_port=9987&use_offline_as_virtual=1&no_query_clients=1' (length=103)** and _string 'serverquery://name:pass@example.com:10011/?server_port=9987&use_offline_as_virtual=1&no_query_clients=1' (length=106)_

Comment: If you upload you file here and @fredirik is correct you will see [three leading characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) https://hexdump.pieterhordijk.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some hidden characters in your `dns.txt` file. Make sure it is encoded UTF-8 *without* BOM.

The UTF-8 BOM is a sequence of bytes (EF BB BF), hence the overhead of three characters.